# Spectral Clustering by Andrew Ng paper: theorem proof question

Tags: spectral-method, clustering

I recently read the paper ["On Spectral Clustering: Analysis and an Algorithm" by Ng *et al*](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/2092-on-spectral-clustering-analysis-and-an-algorithm.pdf).

Much of the paper centers on Theorem 2 and equation 8.
To me, it appears there is no given or referenced proof of this Theorem.
I am hoping that someone can point me in the right direction to understanding the derivation of this result.

Perhaps a longer version of the paper (I am unable to find one so far), or is the result 'obvious' and I am missing something?
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you looked at the papers in the reference list?

Comment: This is my longer term plan. For myself it is quite time consuming to screen these materials. I have started on 4,6,& the first chapter of 3. I was hoping someone with knowledge of the field would be able to give me a pointer to speed things up. Thanks